# Debugging implementation of trait in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, traits

I'm totally lost here.

I have a `Trait` defined as

```
trait TicketServer extends Server {

//comments 
...
def getTicketByEvent(field1: Int, field2: Int...) : Future[TicketByEvent]

//comments
...
def getTicketByUser(field1: Int, field2: Int...) : Future[TicketByUser]

}
trait ticketServerSupport {
     def ticketServer: TicketServer
}
```

This is implemented in:

```
Class TicketServerImpl {

    override def getTicketByEvent(field1: Int, field2: Int...) { //logic }
    override def getTicketByUser(field1: Int, field2: Int...) { //logic }
}
```

Then I then have a another class which calls this method defined like

```
Class Example(fields...) extends Super with TicketServerSupport {

//do logic

   def function() {
       ticketServer.getTicketByEvent(field1, field2...)
       //do logic
   }

}
```

However, getTicketByEvent doesn't do the right thing. So, I've tried debugging, but IntelliJ never seems to actually go into `getTicketByEvent`. So, I tried just throwing in a `println()` in there - because I know it's returning SOMETHING - but it never prints. This seems to imply that it's never actually going into the function. But, it's getting back something! So, it must be going in, right?

Why can't I properly debug this?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clean up your code example so it is possible to compile it please? Right now it looks like `TicketServerImpl` is an abstract class. Also, you don't reference it in the class `Example`.

Comment: How are you calling this code? If you're using an "App" and you're not "waiting" for the future, the app will finish before a result is returned. What is it returning? post more details

Comment: Maybe that's what it is? I'm running some Unit tests that I guess are finishing before it returns. It's just running through the unit tests successfully.

Comment: But, when I do `val x = ticketServer.getTicketByEvent` and `println(x)` in `Class` (which is called by the Unit tests), it prints things it got from the function. So, it's getting **something**, I just don't know how.